# How see status when installing an app from App store?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

When you install a new app from Apple App store, there is no info on how much time is left. How can one find this information?

Answer (score 1):

In App Store Click on Purchase (during the download)

That will show you the progress for your download

[image]

Comment: If it worked for you please check the answer so it will stop popping up as not answered- thank you.